# Python Pandas sum with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my sample data:

```
        Customer   Document Date   Clearing Date   Invoice_Amount
0       A          09/13/2016      11/04/2016      2,007,324
1       A          04/18/2016      07/11/2016      631,714
2       A          09/13/2016      09/16/2016      4,000,000
3       A          07/11/2017      09/23/2017      5,000,000
4       A          05/03/2016      06/17/2016      2,000,000
---     ---        ---             ---             ---
1158    H          04/21/2017      06/28/2017      3,000,000
1159    H          04/25/2017      05/19/2017      1,000,000
1160    H          11/03/2017      12/11/2017      4,500,000
1161    H          03/15/2018      05/27/2018      3,500,000
1162    H          02/21/2018      05/03/2018      1,500,000
```

I want to create a new variable(add a new column after Invoice_Amount) **No_Paid**, which calculate "number of paid invoices prior to the Document date of a new invoice of a customer."

The expected output is as follows...

```
        Customer   Document Date   Clearing Date   Invoice_Amount No_Paid*
0       A          09/13/2016      11/04/2016      2,007,324          8 
1       A          04/18/2016      07/11/2016      631,714            1
2       A          09/13/2016      09/16/2016      4,000,000          8
3       A          07/11/2017      09/23/2017      5,000,000          6
4       A          05/03/2016      06/17/2016      2,000,000          1
---     ---        ---             ---             ---              ---
1158    H          04/21/2017      06/28/2017      3,000,000          5 
1159    H          04/25/2017      05/19/2017      1,000,000          3
1160    H          11/03/2017      12/11/2017      4,500,000          7
1161    H          03/15/2018      05/27/2018      3,500,000         37
1162    H          02/21/2018      05/03/2018      1,500,000         37
```

Currently, I use for loop to achieve the expected output

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('E:\data.csv')
df['Document Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Document Date'],format="%m/%d/%Y")
df['Clearing Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Clearing Date'],format="%m/%d/%Y")
df["No_Paid"] = ""
for i in df.index: 
     Vendor= df.loc[i,"Vendor"]
     Doc_Date= df.loc[i,"Document Date"]
     Six_Month = Doc_Date - pd.Timedelta(days=180)
     df.loc[i,"No_Paid"] = df.loc[(df["Vendor"] == Vendor) & (df["Clearing Date"] < Doc_Date) & (df["Document Date"] >= Six_Month),"Invoice_Amount"].count()
```

In real case, i have over 100,000 invoices data, which take a longer time
I try to use df.apply ...But can't reach the same output...

Comment: Can you share the expected output?

Comment: Hi, i modified the context. Create a column and record the past information (historical data each row)

Comment: I am still not sure what you're trying to achieve here Andy. Ummm, and I've no idea why is it so difficult to understand either. Can you run me through what your VBA code is actually doing. I know what SumProduct does and all, but what are you trying to achieve here. Do you just want for each entry of ID, just create a column against future values to have previous record value? 

Is that so?

Moreover, does you original data(the csv or excel) itself has those ellipses(...) between the rows?

If not, then can you just print the sample sheet as it is?

Comment: See, this can be easily done in Python. 
I am still not sure what you're trying to do here though. Can you run through the values you've calculated and how are you doing it?

Comment: @AndyChu, would you mind posting sample data and expected output that belongs together. it is not clear what you want here.

Comment: Hi Amit and Zanshin, thanks for your comments. I posting sample data, expected output and my python code currently. Is it more clear? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your example:

```
import pandas as pd
# read in csv (save as csv or read in using pd.read_excel)
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
# to datetime just in case
df['Doc_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Doc_Date'])
df['Exp_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Exp_Date'])
df['Overdue'] = df['Doc_Date'] - df['Exp_Date']
# 180 days for 6 months
df['6M_Age'] = df['Doc_Date'] - pd.Timedelta(days=180)
# Hard to tell what the line in the middle of the data means
# you can group by two columns if you need too
df['Sum_of_paid'] = df.groupby('ID').cumsum()
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing Tyler. But the groupby can’t achieve the result, because there are multiple conditions I need to filter. For each data points, the Doc_Date[i] should compare all Act_Date in the overall sample.

Comment: Hi can i use data frame.apply to achieve results?

Comment: Yes, you can use grouby.apply(func) with a custom func if you want. The func will have to input and return a dataframe.